# abrir pagina con window.open y enviarle variable

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tengo un problema, al momento de enviar y registrar en la bd una venta me envía un mensaje de confirmación y eso lo muestro en pantalla:

Este código captura el submit y recibe el mensaje:

```
$(".frm-ventas").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            url:url,
            data:data,
            success:function(response){
                $('#caja').toggle();
                $("span").remove( ".mensaje" );
                $("i").remove('.glyphicon');
                $("#caja").fadeOut(5000);

                if (response.respuesta == true) {
                    $(".box-pago").hide();
                   setTimeout(function(){ 
                   window.open("example/report/factura.php?invoice=reponse.invoice");
                   }, 5000); // 5000 ms                  
                    $('#caja').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-info');
                    $("#caja").append("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign' aria-hidden='true'></i>");
                    $("#caja").append("<span class='mensaje'>"+" ok: "+response.mensaje+"</span>");
                    $('.cargando').toggle();
                    $('.cargando p').html('Limpiando el carrito...');
                    setTimeout(llenar_tabla_json, 2000);
                    limpiarformulario($(".frm-ventas"));

                }else{
                    $('#caja').removeClass('alert-info').addClass('alert-danger');
                    $("#caja").append("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign' aria-hidden='true'></i>");
                    $("#caja").append("<span class='mensaje'>"+" Error: "+response.mensaje+"</span>");
                }
            },error:function(){
                alert("Ha ocurrido un error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Y este es el mensaje:

```
$salidaJson=array('respuesta' => $mensajeOk,'mensaje' => $mensajeError, 'invoice' => $invoice);
            echo json_encode($salidaJson);
```

Quiero abrir esa pagina con `window.open` y enviarle la variable `$invoice` intente con este código y nada

```
window.open("example/report/factura.php?invoice=reponse.invoice");
```

Alguna idea ?

este es la 'variable' $invoice que quiero enviar

$client = new Client();

```
                       $client->setTipoDoc('6')
                              ->setNumDoc(trim($_POST['ruc']))
                              ->setRznSocial(trim($_POST['cliente']))
                              ->setAddress((new Address())
                              ->setDireccion(trim($_POST['direccion'])));
                              // Emisor
                       $address = new Address();
                       $address->setUbigueo($ubigeo)
                              ->setDepartamento($departamento)
                              ->setProvincia($provincia)
                              ->setDistrito($distrito)
                              ->setUrbanizacion($urbanizacion)
                              ->setDireccion($direccionempresa);

                       $company = new Company();
                       $company->setRuc($rucempresa)
                              ->setRazonSocial($razonempresa)
                              ->setNombreComercial($nombre_comercial)
                              ->setAddress($address);
                              // Venta

                       $invoice = new Invoice();
                       $invoice
                              ->setFecVencimiento(new DateTime())
                              ->setTipoDoc($tipo_documento)
                              ->setSerie(trim($_POST['serie']))
                              ->setCorrelativo(trim($_POST['numero']))
                              ->setFechaEmision(new DateTime())
                              ->setTipoMoneda(trim($_POST['pago']))
                              ->setClient($client)
                              ->setMtoOperGravadas($gravadas)                                
                              ->setMtoIGV($importeIGV)
                              ->setMtoImpVenta($importe)
                              ->setCompany($company);
                               $leyenda = trim($_POST['total']);
                       $centimos = substr($leyenda, -2);
                       $legn = validar::convertir($leyenda,'CON '.$centimos.'/100 SOLES');                          
                       $legend = new Legend();
                       $legend->setCode('1000')
                              ->setValue($legn);

                       $invoice->setDetails($items)
                              ->setLegends([$legend]);
```

Comment: Cual es el comportamiento que tiene ?

Comment: Si sólo quieres enviar el valor de `$invoice` entonces necesitarías hacer esto: `$js = "<script>window.open('example/report/factura.php?invoice=$invoice')</script>"; echo $js;`

Comment: es detalle es que $invoice es un ´array´ ya que contiene varios datos

Comment: ya edite mi pregunta

Comment: @FernandoAbelGonzalesCh dio solución a su pregunta ? si no podemos abrir una sala de chat para darle solución ya que por comentarios se hace muy extenso.

Comment: ya lo solucione amigo gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si ya obtienes el valor de `ajax` correctamente es decir en el objeto `response` tendrá las propiedades  *(response.respuesta , response.mensaje, response.invoice)* . Para enviar a `window.open` el valor de `invoice` solo tendría que **concatenar** ese valor *(response.invoice)* al primer parámetro de `window.open` es decir se enviará por `GET` a `factura.php` para luego en `factura.php` pueda acceder por medio `$_GET['invoice']`

```
if (response.respuesta == true) {
  $(".box-pago").hide();
  setTimeout(function(){ 
     window.open("example/report/factura.php?invoice="+response.invoice , '_blank');
 }, 5000); // 5000 ms
```

Desde `factura.php`

```
echo $_GET['invoice'];
```

**Update**

Si el objeto obtenido por Ajax es un `array` , deberá convertir a un formato válido para enviar por `get` lo cuál se logra con [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/).

```
  let invo = $.param(response.invoice);
  setTimeout(function(){ 
     window.open("database.php?invoice=&"+invo , '_blank');
 }, 5000); // 5000 ms
```

Desde `PHP` accedería a las propiedades directamente de `invoice`. por ejemplo si tiene un campo cliente.

```
echo $_GET['cliente'];
```

Comment: esta bien que la variable sea asi ? o quiere decir que esta mal mi variable      localhost:82/invoice/examples/report/factura.php?invoice=[object%20Object]

Comment: esta tal cual lo de example's' fue un error de digito ahora creo me falta mencionar que $invoice es una variable que contiene varios datos

Comment: @FernandoAbelGonzalesCh actualicé mi respuesta, según su comentario. compruebe.

Comment: localhost:82/invoice/examples/report/factura.php?invoice=&

Comment: ahora parece que no envia nada

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at factura.php:2

Comment: no entiendo mucho lo que me dices pero eso bota               
Object ,Object, XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:82/invoice/ventas/registrar_factura"., XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:82/invoice/ventas/listado_carrito". , {respuesta: true, ticket: {…}}